# How to convert a .mat file having 1x1 struct to a.csv file?

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to ouput a .mat file in MATLAB but I am getting this error:

```
a = load('GT_IMG_4.mat');
imshow(a);
```

> Error using `imageDisplayValidateParams`
>   Expected input number 1, `I`, to be one of these types:
>   `double`, `single`, `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `logical`. Instead its type was `struct`.
>
> Error in `images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams` (line 11)
>
> ```
> validateattributes(common_args.CData, {'numeric','logical'},...
> ```
>
> Error in `images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs` (line 78)
>
> ```
> common_args = images.internal.imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);
> ```
>
> Error in `imshow` (line 222)
>
> ```
> images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs({'Parent','Border','Reduce'},preparsed_varargin{:});
> ```

Why am I getting this error and how to resolve this? .mat file is a ground truth of an image. How to look at the .mat file?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `load`? Do you know what variables are saved in the `.mat` file? Have you read how to see the contents of a struct and to access them?

Comment: no i am a newbie for matlab,thats why i am asking for your help

Comment: Please note that the first suggestion in [ask] is "Search, and research".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load()` will return a structure that contains the data in your mat file.

The code below is not correct because `a` is a `struct` which holds your data, not the data itself.

```
a = load('GT_IMG_4.mat');
imshow(a);
```

My guess is that you want to do something like this:

```
h = load('GT_IMG_4.mat'); %I tend to use h to mean handles
imshow(h.a);
```

Note if you type `h` in command window (after loading), you should see the contents of the struct. You might need to dig around a bit to find `a` depending on how you saved your data.

You can technically also do this (assuming `h.a` worked above):

```
load('GT_IMG_4.mat');
imshow(a);
```

This will load the variables from the mat file into the current workspace. Please don't do this. I mean you can ... but it is one of my pet peeves because then you don't know where `a` comes from.

Comment: tq i got it i need to access something like as you said (h.a)